# В чем заключается ошибка ? MarkdownV2

Tags: python, telegram-bot, markdown

Использую маркдаун все нормально отображается но просит использовать 2-ю версию, при использовании маркдаун v2 консоль выдает ошибку.

```
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN, parse_mode=types.ParseMode.MARKDOWN_V2)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('*BSUT Helper*'
                         f'\n{message.from_user.first_name} добро пожпловать! '
                         '\n⬇️Для управления ботом⬇️'
                         '\n⬇️Воспользуйтесь меню ⬇️', reply_markup=menu)
```

Ошибка:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-7' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at D:\Training\Python\Projects\BSUT Helepr (New)\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:380> exception=CantParseEntities("Can't parse entities: character '!' is reserved and must be escaped with the preceding '\\'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Training\Python\Projects\BSUT Helepr (New)\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 388, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "D:\Training\Python\Projects\BSUT Helepr (New)\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 225, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "D:\Training\Python\Projects\BSUT Helepr (New)\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "D:\Training\Python\Projects\BSUT Helepr (New)\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 246, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "D:\Training\Python\Projects\BSUT Helepr (New)\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "D:\Training\Python\Projects\BSUT Helepr (New)\bot.py", line 15, in process_start_command
    await message.answer('*BSUT Helper*'
  File "D:\Training\Python\Projects\BSUT Helepr (New)\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\types\message.py", line 339, in answer
    return await self.bot.send_message(
  File "D:\Training\Python\Projects\BSUT Helepr (New)\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 318, in send_message
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_MESSAGE, payload)
  File "D:\Training\Python\Projects\BSUT Helepr (New)\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 208, in request
    return await api.make_request(self.session, self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "D:\Training\Python\Projects\BSUT Helepr (New)\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 140, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
  File "D:\Training\Python\Projects\BSUT Helepr (New)\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 115, in check_result
    exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
  File "D:\Training\Python\Projects\BSUT Helepr (New)\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 139, in detect
    raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.CantParseEntities: Can't parse entities: character '!' is reserved and must be escaped with the preceding '\'
```

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: @SergBocharov Добавил в описание

Comment: Вроде в тексте ошибки ясно сказано что нужно сделать; что непонятно?

Comment: Я понял, что с ! проблема, а как его отобразить ?

Comment: должен быть экранирован с помощью предшествующего символа '\'

Comment: Заходим в гугл переводчик, вставляем текст ошибки, получаем — «должен быть экранирован предшествующим \»

Comment: А с учётом того, что у строковых литералов в питоне есть своё собственное экранирование, придётся написать слэш два раза `\\!`

Comment: Спасибо большое)